# Из-за чего стили отображаются по разному?

Tags: css

Заметил что одни и те же стили в разных страницах отображаются по разному к примеру:

```
input[type=text]{
  width: 390px
}
```

В странице `index` будет с размером 390px, а в странице `main` будет 390+pх, но точно не 390. Из-за чего может быть такое искажение стилей? Кроме своих стилей я ничего из сторонних не подключал.

Comment: Могу дать ссылку на сам сайт

Comment: За это можно и "по шапке" получить)) Ваш сайт через полгода закроется, и вопрос станет бесполезен. Выкладывайте код

Comment: `http://loca.kg/centerlist` здесь обратите внимание на поисковик, теперь `http://loca.kg/online-shops` здесь

Comment: Для начала добавьте box-sizing:border-box для вашего инпута, тогда ппадинг будет включен в его размеры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию браузеры плюсуют к ширине `input` еще и `padding` и `border`. Также по умолчанию есть и `margin`. Решается просто:

```
input {
  width: 100%;
  /* Убираем влияние padding и border на конечную ширину input */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Обнуляем margin */
  margin: 0;
}
```